# Valgrind report

Tags: c, valgrind

I used the valgrind command

> valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes -v

to check for detected and suppressed errors and got a report on

> ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 8)

What exactly does (suppressed:13 from 8) mean?

Comment: I believe you can actually get hold of the details for those suppressed blocks, possibly by cancelling suppressions with `--suppressions=/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks. Would they relate to the code being checked? What did you mean by known issues?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means there were 13 separate problems - possibly leaked memory, or (more likely) known access errors - from 8 different locations that were not reported because they are known issues and not in your code.  You may be able to alter the suppressions list to see what they are.

Comment: I don't think it's leaks that it's suppressing, I think it's actually access errors. Just like you can suppress complaints (in the thousands) from an ioctl() that Valgrind doesn't know about, operating on anything returned from an ioctl() would result in a warning about use of uninitialized values.

Comment: @Tim: yes, you're correct...I'll rephrase my answer a little.

Comment: Not really: on my current system, there are no access errors as there seemed to be on the OPs system back in 2011.  I currently only have leaks suppressed; no other access errors.